# Linq - Query a List<string[]>

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

How do you query a `List<string[]>` to get the index of the arrays having matches on their sub-arrays and get a return of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string[]>` ?

**EDIT:**

I have this:

```
       string[] report = File.ReadAllLines(@".\REPORT.TXT").AsQueryable().Where(s
       => s.StartsWith(".|")).ToArray();

      List<string[]> mylist = new List<string[]>();

        foreach (string line in report)
        {
            string[] rows = line.Split('|');
            mylist.Add(rows);
        }
```

and I what to get the the mylist indexes where rows[5] == "foo"

Comment: Um...what? :) Could you clarify what you mean by "having matches on their sub-arrays"?  Do you mean that the index of the string[] in the parent List<> matches the number of elements in that string[]?

Comment: How about a code example building the List so we can better see what output you want.

Comment: @Matt Peterson @mpenrow, ok, here some code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the original question:

```
list.Where(array => array.Any(item => item == match))
```

For the updated one:

```
result = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count - 1).Where(i => list[i][5] == "foo");
```

You do actually need to check if the array has at least 6 items as well:

```
i => list[i].Length > 5 && list[i][5] == "foo"
```

Comment: I think you mean `Where` instead of `Select`. The code you've posted will return an `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Comment: @sukru: Happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: I've edited my question with some code, but how does this return an index ?

Comment: Added another solution for the updated version of the problem.

Comment: +1 on Dan Tao's comment, you should do a .ToList() at the end if you need it to be in a List<T>.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
var haystacks = new List<string[]>();

haystacks.Add(new string[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" });
haystacks.Add(new string[] { "abc", "ghi" });
haystacks.Add(new string[] { "def" });

string needle = "def";

var haystacksWithNeedle = haystacks
    .Where(haystack => Array.IndexOf(haystack, needle) != -1);
```